# Bluemix and the Remote Systems View in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I just updated all of my plugins and noticed the "Application and Services" tab of the IBM Bluemix view has a link says "Show deployed files in Remote Systems View". When I click on that link, it opens the view and I can drill down to my apps but it does not show me any files or anything useful. Can this view (or a different view) show file contents on bluemix? This would be really useful especially since the files app was removed when the Diego upgrade happened.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using Neon.2 with the latest version of the IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix from the Eclipse market place and deploy a new application. The Remote System View is showing the files correctly for me.

Note that the problem may happen for older version of the product.  What version of the product (Eclipse and Bluemix Tools) and also what platform are you using?

The other thing that you can try is to deploy a new simple application to see if the problem is specific to that application.

Answer (score 0):

It does show the files that are deployed. Attached is an image that I see

[image: Eclipse Runtime Files]

Comment: I downloaded Neon 2, installed the latest plugins and it worked. The version I used originall that did not work was Mars 1 with the latest plugins (as of Mar 9). Thanks!